# How to make sumsung galaxy tab 3 device rooted

Tags: android

I want to make my sumsung galaxy tab rooted. But I have no idea how to do it? I have google so much but don't get any perfect solution or answer.

Please help me how can crack this problem.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Sorry not a Developement Question but the go to XDA Developers Website and ull find there the answer

Answer (score 0):

. Before You Begin
1. This will void the warranty of your device. However, you can reinstate the warranty by unrooting your device if there’s any unrooting procedure available.

1. This procedure only works on Windows based PCs.

II. Downloading Required Files
1. Download Odin and save it to your Desktop.

Odin

1. Download CWM Recovery and save it to your Desktop.

CWM Recovery (It’s attached in the first post)

1. Download Universal Root ZIP and save it to your Desktop.

Universal Root ZIP (It’s attached in the first post)

III. Flashing a Custom Recovery on the Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 7.0 (Sprint)
1. Extract files from both Odin and CWM Recovery by right-clicking on each of them and selecting Extract here.

1. Double-click on Odin executable and it should launch.
2. Click on PDA and choose the CWM Recovery that you just extracted to your Desktop.
3. Make sure Repartition is unchecked in the Odin.
4. Uncheck the Auto Reboot option as well.
5. Turn OFF your device.
6. Turn it back on by holding down Volume DOWN+Home+Power buttons together.
7. Press Volume UP and you should be in Download mode.
8. Plug in your device to your PC using the USB cable.
9. Hit Start in the Odin and it’ll start flashing the recovery on your device.
10. Once done, reboot your device.
11. You’re done!

IV. Rooting the Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 7.0 (Sprint)
1. Connect your device to your PC via USB cable.

1. Copy the Universal Root ZIP from your Desktop over to the root of your SD card.
2. Once it’s been copied, disconnect your device from your PC.
3. Turn OFF your device.
4. Turn it back on by holding down Volume UP+Home+Power buttons together.
5. When the Samsung logo appears, release the Power button but keep holding the other two.
6. You should now be in Recovery mode.
7. Select install zip from sdcard followed by choose zip from sdcard.
8. Choose the Universal Root ZIP to be flashed on your device.
9. It should start flashing the ZIP on your device.
10. Once it’s done, reboot your device.
11. You’re now rooted!

All set! Now, you can head to our How to Flash a Custom ROM procedure for the Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 7.0 (Sprint) to open up a whole new world of customizations for your Android device!

By the way, don’t be scared, you can always put your device back to stock by heading to our Rooting How To’s section, finding your device, and doing the How to Unroot listed for it there.

Comment: this question is not intended for so

Comment: then what is your main goal??

Comment: @angle sorry for that .. I have already try given procedure from this link http://theunlockr.com/2014/02/17/root-samsung-galaxy-tab-3-7-0/       and It's not working for my device (Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 )

Comment: Actually I wanna to make it rooting device